# Only allow one data-toggle at a time for multiple options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner with javascript and jquery, I am using opencart and a filter extension.

I am trying to get only one data-toggle to show at a time.

The filter extension has multiple options like category, size, category, colour, etc. Each option when clicked shows a hidden div when when clicked again hides it.

Each option can be clicked and all hidden divs can be shown at the same time. I am trying to make only one option show at a time, so for example option A is clicked it opens but if option B is clicked while A is open - B opens and A closes. Kind of like a toggle.

I believe the javascript doing this is in the bootstap.js include. But each option clicked does this to it's html:

When a option is clicked (Open):

```
<div class="af-container"> 
<div class="af-heading af-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#s"> 
<p>Category:</p><span></span> 
</div> 
<div aria-expanded="false" id="s" class="af-elements collapse" style="height: 0px;"> 
</div> 
</div>
```

When open **collapsed** class is added and aria-expanded is set to **"false"**, in the div below aria-expanded is set to **"false"** also.

When an open option is click (Closed):

```
<div class="af-container"> 
<div class="af-heading af-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" data-target="#s"> 
<p>Category:</p><span></span> 
</div> 
<div aria-expanded="true" id="s" class="af-elements collapse in" style=""> 
</div> 
</div>
```

When closed **collapsed** class is removed and aria-expanded is set to **"true"** and in the following div aria-expanded is set to **"true"** and **in** class is added to div, also **height** is removed from style.

The "html" code seems to be within a .tag file:

```
 <af_group>
    <div class="af-container">
        <div class="af-heading af-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{filter.name}_{filter.group_id}_{opts.filter_id}" aria-expanded="true">
            <p class="title">{filter.caption}</p><span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="{filter.name}_{filter.group_id}_{opts.filter_id}"  class="af-elements collapse {filter.collapse == '0'?'in':''}" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="af-wrapper">
                <div data-is='af_group_{filter.type}' filter={filter} filter_id={opts.filter_id}></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </af_group>
```

What is the best way to only have one open at a time? Is there a simple solution or would maybe javascript that overrides / adds to the bootstrap.js (if it is that) to allow only one collapsed class to be allowed at a time for example?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: @Gerardo BLANCO I'm trying to add `data-parent="#myGroup"` to each, then with jquery only allow one to be open is this a way to do it or would this not work? I've had no luck yet. Here is my current code: `var $myGroup = $('#myGroup');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapsed', function() {
    $myGroup.find('.collapse .in').collapse('');
});   `

Comment: Sounds close, but i would really need to see a live example to actually debug and give you an answer.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO basically it is just .in class which is added to show the drop down. I need only one occasion of class "in" to be allowed like a toggle.

Comment: all the element have the class ``collapse ``?

Comment: yes all have class="collapse", when data-toggle="collapse" is clicked the element has class="collapse in". The problem is 3 elements can have class="collapse in" at the same time, I want just one to be able to have the in class.

Comment: aria-expanded="false" for closed, and aria-expanded="true" for open?

Comment: correct @GerardoBLANCO

Comment: I have made an answer. If you want to continue the conversation there so we can work on it and improve it if necesarie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example with out changing the aria tags.

I added some css so we can see how it works

Hope this helps :)

```js
//Event listener
$('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').parent().click(function() {
  $('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function() {
    //Reset values for all
    $(this).addClass('collapsed');
    $(this).next().removeClass('in');
  })
  //Change values for the selected one
  $(this).children().removeClass('collapsed');
  $(this).children().next().addClass('in');
})
```

```css
.af-container {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px lightblue solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.af-container .collapsed {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px pink solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px pink solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  display: none;
}

.in{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="af-container">
  <div class="af-heading af-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#s">
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-container">
  <div class="af-heading af-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#s">  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>

</div>
<div class="af-container">
  <div class="af-heading af-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#s">  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>

</div>
```

The problem in your site is that you have two element in question.

1. The button
2. The dropdown

I thought the secon one was a children from the first one. I was wrong.

In your case they are siblings. I addapted my snippet to represent this.

If you paste the next code in your site, it should work like a charm.

```
$('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').parent().click(function(){
    $('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
        //Reset values for all
        $(this).next().removeClass('in');
      })
      //No need to add anything, your site does this for you
});
```

Comment: This seems perfect, I can't understand why it's not working for me. Is jquery possibly overruling? It is ignoring the java script and allowing many cases of .in.

Comment: It is hard to tell, i would recommend you to add a live example so i can help you with debuging it :)

Comment: it seems to be having no effect I think something is blocking it?

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: Dont know whats wrong, i cant even set an event listener for your header. You can copy paste my code in the console and see that it works. But i cant find what is blocking it

Comment: really strange :/ what if I change away from data-toggle collapse? From my original post is there maybe a way to avoid collapse all together?

Comment: There might be, but the real problem is that there i dont know why any code you add wont work. First solve thant, then my answer solves your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168946/discussion-between-beth-and-gerardo-blanco).

Comment: I almost solved with this solution, I had to put onclick function on the div. The only problem is it toggles when the child is clicked also?

Comment: Could you check discussion one last time @Gerardo BLANCO

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myGroup = $('#myGroup');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function(e) {
    $myGroup.find('.collapse.show').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Not sure why but this is giving me a syntax error and not working?

Comment: Probably because of the ES6 syntax. I've updated my answer to ES5. Give it another shot.